# How to fix permission denied while running vendor/bin/phpunit in a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Whenever I execute `vendor/bin/phpunit` in root path of my laravel project, it gives back a *Permission denied* error. How can I fix this problem?

Important: I don't want to use `composer update` or delete some or all the `vendor/` dir then use `composer install` as these methods will change too much files, which my master will not agree.

> ps: lrwxrwxrwx 1 work work   26 Jul 21 07:10 phpunit ->
>   ../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
>
> -rwxrwxrwx  1 work work  1199 Jul 22 08:19 ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit

and  `chmod 775 -R vendor` doesn't work.

Comment: Check the right on `vendor/bin/phpunit`

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx, I hope this issue is that easy,but it is not

Comment: Are you logged as `work`?

Comment: yep,I logged in as work

Comment: chown group apache www-datda:www-data

Comment: `vendor/bin/phpunit` is a symbolic link to `../phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` check the right there.

Comment: @Vuldo -rwxrwxrwx 1 work work 1199 Jul 22 08:19 ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit

Answer (score 34):

What you should do is call with php:

```
$ php ./vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 4.8.35 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
```

I get the same error tying to execute it without php interpreter:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit
bash: ./vendor/bin/phpunit: Permission denied
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! Even the composer vendor binary documentation does not say this. https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md

Comment: This is a valid workaround, but it doesn't solve the permission issue. If it works with `php`, but doesn't work without `php`, it means that the actual executable in `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` does not have the `x` bit on.

Comment: Hi @MaksimIvanov I agree with you, but at the time I wrote this answer make files executable (eg: chmod a+x) did not fix it. Currently, I am not able to replicate the issue anymore so can not tell why this happens and if there is any other solution.

Comment: if you have more PHP versions, make sure you are calling the right one e.g. `php7.1 ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

Answer (score 7):

Deleting the `vendor` folder and doing `composer install` worked for me.

Comment: change my project folder name and user ownership, I think this is the best approach for my case. thanks

Comment: same for me, i installed dependency with composer out of container context, i deleted the folder and i started the container : docker exec -ti <container_id> bash  and then rm vendo and composer install

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by updating the Vagrantfile of your setup, particularly the `fmode` of your web root `synced_folder` folder.

Change:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

to :

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]
```

For scotch-box,

Change:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=666"]
```

to :

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", :mount_options => ["dmode=777", "fmode=777"]
```

After doing this, reload your configuration:

```
$ vagrant reload
```

Comment: Who said anything about vagrant? Im marking this down as the question never mentions vagrant.

Comment: While you are absolutely right that no Vagrant was mentioned in the question, it seems to be a common unmentioned problem connected with this error message. At least it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

What you see in the `vendor/bin` directory is **symlinks**. Symlinks might have the right permissions, but the files they are pointing to might not. Ensure that both symlinks and the files they are pointing to have the execute (`x`) bit on.

```
# symlink
sudo chmod 0775 vendor/bin/phpunit

# the actual executable
sudo chmod 0775 vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and open your terminal and issue the command:
The 1st one with the -R Flag means *change permission also for sub-directories -*  **R** *ecursive*

```
sudo chmod 777 -R PATH_TO/vendor

sudo chmod 777 PATH_TO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit

sudo chmod 777 PATH_TO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit && chmod +x PATH_TO/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Comment: thx a lot，I used /vendor/bin/php* in the 3rd command,but it still gives me a :Permission denied,hahaha...

Comment: @JinAazoe  not /vendor/bin/php but `/vendor/bin/phpunit` ... sorry... check again... think the problem is because you are all files in /bin directory are sym-Links... so the code was again updated ;-)

Comment: thank you again,but doesn't work,I think simply chmod cant save my ass ,I think it has something to do with the laravel framwork

Answer (score 0):

When on linux,  scripts won't be executed on filesystem mounted with noexec option

do a

```
mount | grep noexec
```

and see if your filesystem has execution disabled